# Java Maven Error loading property file

Tags: java, maven, properties

im trying to deploy a jar file but it's says: BUILD FAILURE
how can i fix it ? here is an error and down below i posted a pom file. thanks in advence.
should i also paste a properties file ?

it contain one line only: `version=${project.version}`

```
[WARNING] Command line option -npr is deprecated and will be removed in future Maven versions.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Zamocno Calculator 1.1.6
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact jfreechart:jfreechart:jar:1.0.0 has been relocated to jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.0
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ ZamocnoCalculator ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.513s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun May 26 20:07:12 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/76M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) on project ZamocnoCalculator: Error loading property file 'E:\solsoft\ZamocnoCalculator\version.properties' -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

POM.XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ZamocnoCalculator</groupId>
    <artifactId>ZamocnoCalculator</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.1.6</version>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <id>codehausSnapshots</id>
            <name>Codehaus Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://snapshots.maven.codehaus.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        </resources>
        <filters>
            <filter>version.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>bbstats.gui.RunFrame</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <name>Zamocno Calculator</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <organization>
        <name>Vardius and Daszczu Software Engineering</name>
    </organization>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
            <artifactId>forms_rt</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jfreechart</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.10</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Does `E:\solsoft\ZamocnoCalculator\version.properties` exist?

Comment: Maybe you should use the `-e` switch then to get more info.

Comment: Is the build running on your machine where Maven can access `E:\`?

Comment: Why do you need a version.properties file? Why not using the META-INF.MF file or Templates etc. ?